# CakePHP find+list with multilevel group

Tags: cakephp, group-by, grouping

Is it possible in CakePHP to execute a find('list', ...) query from which I get a list grouped in more than one level?

For example, if I want a list of users grouped by their roles, but also by the code of their referral contact, I would have something like this:

```
$usernameGroups = $this->Article->User->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('User.username', 'User.first_name', 
                          'User.referral', 'User.group'));
```

And I want this output:

```
$usernameGroups = Array
(
    ['User'] => Array
    (
        ['AxVc'] => Array
        (
            ['PHPNut'] => 'Larry',
            ['gwoo'] => 'Gwoo'
        )
        ['EQbd'] => Array
        (
            ['IronMan'] => 'Tony',
            ['Hulk'] => 'Bruce'
        )
    )

    ['Admin'] => Array
    (
        ['AxVc'] => Array
        (
            ['_psychic_'] => 'John',
            ['AD7six'] => 'Andy',
            ['jperras'] => 'Joël'
        )
    )

)
```

Obviously I tried this and it did not work. If I leave only three fields it works perfect. Since I 'm pretty new to Cake probably I'm missing something. Is there any workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`find('list')` allow only 2 or 3 fields.

You can use `find('threaded')` or use `Hash::nest()`.

Comment: But for what I understand these methods create a tree structure, with a recursive model. This is not what I need since I don't have any field to recurse by. I just want a group_by kind of behavior, as in a report.